# Trying to get data of last three months

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to find out how many times Kiln stopped in last three months. I have the following query:

```
SELECT SUM(kiln_no_stops) from monthly_report 
where date BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(NOW() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH, '%m-%Y') 
AND DATE_FORMAT(NOW() , '%m-%Y')
```

When I use this query I get this error

> Unknown column 'date' in 'where clause'.

But I am able to get the data for last one month using the query below:

```
SELECT SUM(kiln_no_stops) 
from monthly_report 
where date_format(yesterday,'%m-%Y')=Date_format(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH,'%m-%Y')
```

How can I get the data "Total number of stops" for the last three months?

Comment: looks like your field name is `yesterday` not `date`

Comment: You shouldn't use `%m-%Y` format when comparing dates, use `%Y-%m`. Otherwise `12-2013` will be greater than `01-2014`.

Comment: `date` is reserved keyword in mysql. Try with some other keyword such as tran_date etc. This might be the issue.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai it's reserved but you can still use it if you enclose it within backticks. : \`date\`

Comment: Ok, is there any general query for getting last three months data or to get data from 'x' month to 'y' month? My table is in a SCADA tool that uses MySQL for database connection. Yes there is no date column. But I don't know what can I use instead of date. If I use tran_date instead of date, still I'm getting the same error - Unknown Column 'tran_date' in 'where clause'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if this would help you:

```
SELECT SUM(kiln_no_stops) 
from monthly_report 
where yesterday >= now()-interval 3 month;
```

**EDIT:**

To get last 3 months data (March1 to May31, current date = June 18)

```
SELECT SUM(kiln_no_stops) 
from monthly_report where month(yesterday) < month(now())
AND yesterday >= cast( (last_day(now()) + interval 1 day - interval 4 month) as date);
```

Comment: I Assume Monthly_report has a date field variable named "YESTERDAY"